# NSLayoutConstraint error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

Anyone have any clues on how to fix this?  I tried doing what they suggested, but nothing I do fixes it.

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
    (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd2af8f0 H:[UIView:0xd2a2530(302)]>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd467760 H:[UIView:0xd2a2530]-(9)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xd2af800 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd2afce0 H:|-(400)-[UIView:0xd2a2530]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xd2af800 )>",
        "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x179be3d0 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0xd2af800(320)]>"
    )

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0xd2af8f0 H:[UIView:0xd2a2530(302)]>
```

I am moving a view on and off screen. Here is the code I use to move it off screen (i.e. where the error is happening).

```
-(void)reverseSetPickupHoverView {

self.confirmLocationViewHeightConstraint.constant = 149.0f;
self.confirmLocationViewWidthConstraint.constant = 302.0f;
self.confirmLocationViewLeftsideConstraint.constant = 400.0f;
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's reorder the first three items from the error:

```
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd2afce0 H:|-(400)-[UIView:0xd2a2530]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xd2af800 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd2af8f0 H:[UIView:0xd2a2530(302)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd467760 H:[UIView:0xd2a2530]-(9)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xd2af800 )>",
```

So, from the superview leading edge there's 400 + 302 + 9 == 711 points of space to its trailing edge. Now:

```
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x179be3d0 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0xd2af800(320)]>"
```

That superview is constrained to be 320 points wide. 711 != 320. That's the conflict.

The superview's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property is set to true, which is where that last constraint comes from. I'm not sure what you tried, but it wasn't setting that property to false.

What's the superview's superview? Is it something controlled by the system? In that case, you won't be able to clear its `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property. Instead, you'll have to make your constraints more flexible to cope with the system-imposed restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you put in one too many constraints in the storyboard. Autolayout attempts to figure out X, Y, Width, and Height. In this case, height of the UIView is set by two parameters: 1.) it's constrained to 302, and 2.) by having a vertical spacing of (9) and (400)    respectively from the top/bottom of some other views.

Case 1 is obvious. You say, it has to be 302 high. Case 2 is less obvious. If the superview is 1000 px high for example, then your view must be 591 px high (a view that is 9 from the top, and 400 from the bottom...)

So there's a conflict, and autolayout blows away one of the two.

How I'd fix it: Clear all constraints, and then set them either manually or by reset to suggested values.